# Keypress to insert certain operator (row of characters)

Tags: visual-studio-code, kde-plasma

I love to insert <%= at the press of a keybinding.
KDE or VSCode.

I already looked into the official documentation, and could only find keybinding settings for commands.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does it:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets

It was supposed to insert <%=